# Formal way to say "pay off"?

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to write an Abstract and need to change the sentence

> I believe that the work load for the physicians will pay off by increasing patient safety.

I was wondering if there is a more formal way to say that something *pays off*?

Answer (score 1):

It will be *compensated for, redeemed, justified*. And there must be no comma before *that*.

Comment: I like "I believe that the additional work load for the physicians will be justified by an increase in patient safety."

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Me too.

Answer (score 0):

The service might be *remunerated* as well.

Comment: It might well: but *it might be paid* (or *pay well)* has nothing to do with whether it *pays off*.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but you could simplify and clarify that sentence as "I believe that the workload for the physicians will increase patient safety." - but actually for an even better sentence you should say what it is about the workload that you believe will cause this increase. And personally I would spell "workload" as one word, although both variants are ok (but think about the word count in your abstract ;) ).

Comment: You are nearly three years late unfortunately.